# split string by rows and add to listbox

Tags: c#, string

I have big result from unix command in string format(list of files in unix directory, from command "ll *files_mask*"). I need to split this big string by rows(one row - one filename) and every row add to listbox as item. How I can do it? I have to use string massive?

Comment: what have you done?

Comment: Can you share the example string? And how you want to split and how it should look like after split?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this methods.

```
var Items = UnixResult.Split("\\r?\\n");
```

or

```
var Items = UnixResult.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

or

```
var Items = UnixResult.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```